# How to get a Chrome web extension to read Chrome setting "Ask where to save each file before downloading"?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, settings

I was wondering if there was a way the extension could read whether the setting was on or off so that we could notify the user if it needs to be changed for use of the extension.
I have checked all over the internet to try to find an answer to this. All I found on Stack Overflow is that the extension cannot change this setting at all. I tried chrome.contentSettings and chrome.downloads, but neither worked for this situation. 
The closest I got is that chrome.downloads can access the path to the default download file, which is the setting right above this one. Does anyone have any ideas on how to achieve this? Thanks

Comment: There's no way other than [writing a native utility](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging) that will access the file system directly to check the setting in user profile's preferences file.